# How to prevent starting the activity at the first tab in a TabActivity?

Tags: android

I have a TabActivity, which contains 4 activities. My code sets the second tab as the current tab:

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

    TextView tabView;

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity1.class);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ff_tab_indicator, null);
    tabView.setText("Tab 1");
    spec.setIndicator(tabView);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity2.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ff_tab_indicator, null);
    tabView.setText("Tab 2");
    spec.setIndicator(tabView);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity3.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ff_tab_indicator, null);
    tabView.setText("Tab 3");
    spec.setIndicator(tabView);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity4.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 4");
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ff_tab_indicator, null);
    tabView.setText("Tab 4");
    spec.setIndicator(tabView);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}
```

The problem is, when the MyTabActivity starts, it starts both activity in the first tab and the activity in the second tab. I just want it to start the activity in the second tab, since it is set to be the current tab. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: @kknight: Besides not use activities as the content of tabs?

Comment: @kknight: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to set tab 2 as default tab. When the tab activity starts, only the activity in tab 2 gets started. Currently, Android starts both activity in tab 1 and activity in tab 2, if I set tab 2 as default current tab.

Comment: Rephrase. I set tab 2 as default tab using tabHost.setCurrentTab(1). When the tab activity starts, I expect that only the activity in tab 2 gets started. But, currently, Android starts both activity in tab 1 and activity in tab 2, if I set tab 2 as default current tab.

Comment: @CommonsWare, do you suggest not using activities at all with Tabs? The android documentation lists this as an option, but if what the OP is asking for isn't possible, using activities in Tabs is basically unusable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just reordering the Tabs so that the default becomes the first?

Comment: Indeed. That's a solution. Not sure I want to change the order of the layout of my UI every time the app starts up though. A bit of a confusing XP IMO.